# Glass cartridge fuses, what does the "P" suffix mean?

Tags: power, identification, components

The IEC 127 standard for glass cartridge fuses ends with a voltage rating, "###V". I have a fuse with a "P" suffix after that, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

Found it..."P" means lead-free.

Comment: Please consider improving your answer by linking to your source and/or including a screenshot of your source, and quoting it.